# Why does the same docker image consume different amounts of memory on different environments

Tags: docker

I am running the same docker image, both locally on my Mac laptop, and on an Ubuntu machine on the cloud. I noticed that it consumes 350MB on my machine while it takes 2.7GB on the remote machine.
Remote:Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a.
Local:Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962

Eventually I used all my memory on that machine (32GB) and went to a bigger one (64GB) with same docker version. I saw every container now takes 5GB.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Speaking from my own experience in this matter. It seems that if you don't specify a memory limit when running a docker container, you would get a default chunk of memory. The bigger your machine RAM is, the bigger chunk you get. 
One I set the limit to 1GB (docker run -m=1g) the process only used ~300MB, like it should.
So, my advice is, when running multiple instances of an image, consider setting -m flag.